# Pronunciation of "Lives"

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I often wonder what is the proper pronunciation of "lives", like how would I pronounce "human lives", am I suppose to pronounce it like:

> Leeves

Like `i` in `thing`.

Or more like:

> Laives

Like `i` in `I'm`.

I usually say the "Leeves" way, but I mostly hear people say the "Laives" version.

I would like to know the proper pronunciation of "lives".

Comment: This dictionary may help you. I use it myself and it is useful: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb "to live" has a short /ɪ/ sound.  It is the same sound as in "sit" (and not the same as in seat or in site)

The noun "a life" and the plural "many lives" has the dipthong /aɪ/ It is the same sound as in "site".

> Cats have nine lives  (/laɪvz/)
>
> He lives in Boston (/lɪvz/)

Comment: The IPA spelling is important too (*/laɪvz/* and */lɪvz/*) because different accents will pronounce sounds in different ways. So there's no one correct pronunciation, but there are some common ones, and the consistency with other words is what's important.